# Подсчет координат при передвижении в игре

Tags: c++, glut

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема не с кодом, а с математикой. Когда я смотрю верх или вниз, и нажимаю клавишу вперед, то я очень сильно ускоряюсь (буквально выхожу за пределы карты). Как правильно расчитать Y? Мне нужно, чтобы персонаж летал с нормальной скоростью.

*Как рассчитывается нажатие клавиш и двигается игрок:*

```
if (key == EV_FORWARD_KEY) {
 P_POS_D.x -= sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
 P_POS_D.y += tan(angleY / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime; // Проблема здесь.
 P_POS_D.z -= cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
}else if (key == EV_BACK_KEY) {
 P_POS_D.x += sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
 P_POS_D.y -= tan(angleY / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime; // Проблема здесь.
 P_POS_D.z += cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
}

if (key == EV_LEFT_KEY) {
 P_POS_D.x += sin((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
 P_POS_D.z += cos((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
}else if (key == EV_RIGHT_KEY) {
 P_POS_D.x += sin((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
 P_POS_D.z += cos((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed * ftime;
}
```

*Как это передается OpenGL:*

```
P_POS.x += P_POS_D.x;
P_POS.y += P_POS_D.y;
P_POS.z += P_POS_D.z;
P_POS_D.x = P_POS_D.y = P_POS_D.z = 0;

P_VIEW.x = P_POS.x + w / 2 - sin(angleX / 180 * PI);
P_VIEW.y = P_POS.y + h_eye + tan(angleY / 180 * PI);
P_VIEW.z = P_POS.z + d     - cos(angleX / 180 * PI);
gluLookAt(P_POS.x + w / 2, P_POS.y + h_eye, P_POS.z + d, P_VIEW.x, P_VIEW.y, P_VIEW.z, P_UPVIEW.x, P_UPVIEW.y, P_UPVIEW.z); //P_UPVIEW - x = 0 y = 1 z = 0
```

*Как рассчитывается поворот камеры:*

```
POINT EV_M_POS;
GetCursorPos(&EV_M_POS);

int win_c_w = win_w / 2, // win_w - ширина окна, win_h - высота
 win_c_h = win_h / 2;

angleX += (win_c_w - EV_M_POS.x) / 4;
angleY += (win_c_h - EV_M_POS.y) / 4;

if (angleX > 360)
 angleX -= 360;
else if (angleX < -360)
 angleX += 360;

if (angleY < -90)
 angleY = -90;
else if (angleY > 90)
 angleY = 90;

SetCursorPos(win_c_w, win_c_h);
```

Comment: P. S. Свободное передвижение.

Comment: Проблема тангунса в том, что если угол равен 90 градусам, то результат будет бесконечность. Я пробовал использовать синус, но я не знаю, что использовать вместо тангунса в gluLookAt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, речь идет о задании направления движения с помощью сферических координат. Википедия на помощь:

[image: Из сферических в декартовы]

[Сферическая система координат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82)